# EJS: How can I make my content take up the whole screen (e.g. width: 100%)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

so I'm a beginner and I am learning HTML, CSS, JS, EJS, Express and making web apps. Basically, I'm trying to learn full stack. I am currently working on a web app and I'm using EJS as my templating engine as well as static HTML files for the non-dynamic parts of my web app.

I can get the HTML working perfectly in EJS templates, however I'm experiencing issues getting my CSS to work.

I have set up routes for serving static files:

```
app.set("view options", { layout: false });
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

CSS works, seemingly perfectly except for the fact that my content doesn't take up the whole page.
It's like the width: 100% property doesn't work, or maybe it does but EJS has certain constraints or something that I do not know about.

Again, I am a beginner and I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Are the CSS files loading?  
And what does your HTML and CSS look like? Have you tested it in a browser directly from the file system, making sure everything is working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

EJS is just an HTML-template engine, which have no difference from the usual one written by HTML(in the simplest case). So, you should try to find what's wrong in your CSS styles;

Even if you have not configured your node server to give you the correct CSS styles, you can simply write the necessary styles inside the tag  in the EJS file itself and check if everything works as expected.

Also, to check why your HTML elements do not look as intended, use the [developer console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open) in your browser.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Of course, it was a mistake on my part and my CSS was faulty. I guess we learn by making mistakes